# Error - Unknown listen EADDRINUSE :::5432 in Windows Powershell

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gulp, node-modules

On running gulp serve --nobrowser, I get the following error:

```
{ Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5432
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1355:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1480:7)
at SpfxServeTask.executeTask (C:\Users\lipalath\_\EUS-Col-ColPub- 
PublishApps\PublishApps\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build- 
serve\lib\ServeTask.js:70:65)   
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 5432 }
[13:25:31] Error - Unknown
 listen EADDRINUSE :::5432
{ Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:4321
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
typeof-compare is deprecated. Starting from TypeScript 2.2 the compiler 
includes this check which makes this rule redundant.
```

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when I was running the command `gulp serve`. The gulp was serving already in a different terminal, and without checking that, I was running the `gulp serve` in a different terminal.

[image]

So I had to close one terminal and run the command `gulp serve` again. You can also stop one terminal by pressing CTRL + c.

This is applicable for `gulp watch` as well.